# Render tree structure of unknown depth using Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, recursion, razor, blazor

I'm using the following recursive function to try and render out an html accordion.
It uses reflection to gather all property names and values of a given object. The object is a data tree structure of unknown depth/children etc.

```
@* Accordoin HTML Template *@
<div class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" id="accordion-1" name="accordion-checkbox" hidden>
   <label class="accordion-header" for="accordion-1">
    <i class="icon icon-arrow-right mr-1"></i>
    Title
   </label>
<div class="accordion-body">
    <!-- Accordions content -->
</div>
</div>

@code { 
public void BuildTree(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return;
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            //Build accordion body
        }
        else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
        {
            //Build accordion header
            IEnumerable enumerable = (IEnumerable)propValue;
            if (enumerable != null)
                foreach (object child in enumerable)
                    BuildTree(child);
        }
        else
        {
            //Build accordion header
            BuildTree(propValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**My question is how would I go about rendering the html in a recursive way?**

I have tried using a RenderFragment as follows :

```
RenderFragment BuildTree(object obj)
{
if (obj == null) return @<p>test</p>;
Type objType = obj.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
    if (property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
       return @<p>Some test markup</p>
    }
    else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
    {
        IEnumerable enumerable = (IEnumerable)propValue;
        if (enumerable != null)
            foreach (object child in enumerable)
                BuildTree(child);
    }
    else
    {
        BuildTree(propValue);
    }
}
return @<p>Done</p>;
}
```

It builds but gives an error on runtime :

**Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.**

I know there must be an idiomatic way to do this in blazor but I can't wrap my head around how recursion would work with render fragments.

Comment: Are you building the render tree programmatically as an exercise or because you think this is the only way to render a tree structure?

Comment: No I'm pretty convinced that there are other ways. What's your take on it?

Comment: Was going to respond with Benny's answer, so I've +1'd it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My 2 cents: components can be self-nested.  For my brain, this is the easiest way to render nested components-- a kind of very physical recursion.  I'm at work, so I couldn't finish a working solution for you, but hopefully the following template will be clear enough.  If you want all branches to display, then drop the boolean logic completely or initialize ShowChildren to true instead of false;

**Nestable.Razor**

```
@if(ChildCollection is not null){
    <div @onclick=ToggleVisibility >
        <u>@DisplayForThisObject</u>
    </div>
     @if(ShowChildren){
         foreach (var Child in ChildCollection){
            <Nestable PassedObject=Child />
         }
     }
}
else {
    @DisplayForThisObject;
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public object PassedObject {get; set;}
    IEnumerable<object> ChildCollection {get; set;}
    string DisplayForThisObject {get; set;}
    bool ShowChildren {get; set;} = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        DisplayForThisObject = SomePropertyToString();
        ChildCollection = SomemethodToGetTheChildObjects(PassedObject);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
    void ToggleVisibility(){
        ShowChildren = !ShowChildren;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah!!. A component calling itself. I think this will put me on the right path. Thanks Benny. Will give it a shot.

Comment: Good luck.  Let us know how it works out!

Comment: I've tried but to no avail. I'm getting infinite recursion. I made sure that "SomemethodToGetTheChildObjects()" gives me an IEnumerable<object> and "SomePropertyToString()" gives me the name of a given property.

Comment: Ahhhhh, Nevermind.. I got it working. Late night here in South Africa. I was instantiating the PassedObject within the nested component.

Comment: Greetings from Cape Town @ryang! Please do share your findings! 

Comment: How can I proceed to make parent>child>child>

Comment: Above code just provides parent without child and with multiple only

Comment: Read it again.  Especially, read the file name, and the name of the object used in the markup.

Comment: @sumitkhatrii if you can give an example of your datastructure, and if you're still confused, I can modify the example to understand more easily.  I left it very open so that you can use it with any class and any data source you want.